# Swift-Firebase multiple observers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

In a view controller, I have multiple observer codes. All of them working correctly except one. I'm sure child paths are correct. Observe function is correct. I tried in different a view controller and it worked correctly. Here is my firebase structure:
[image: Firebase structure]

And here is my observer function.

```
func downloadUserData(){
    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
        print("AZAT: download user data id \(currentUser.uid))")
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid).observe(  .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
            print("AZAT: userdict is \(userDict)")
            let user = User(userData: userDict)
            self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
        }
        })
    }
}
```

And I call this function in `viewDidLoad()`. The `REF_USERS` is correct, I'm pretty sure.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: All right, seems decent enough, What is the issue? Errors? Which line?

Comment: I can see print("AZAT: download user data id \(currentUser.uid))") in console. But i can't see print("AZAT: userdict is \(userDict)") in console. The observe doesn't working @Dravidian

Comment: Then most probably it isn't Dictionary, Try printing snapshot itself

Comment: I tried it, i doesn't even get in the observe function. I tried before if let userDict statement, It didn't work.

Comment: What is `DataService.ds.REF_USERS`?

Comment: FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users"). When i copy and paste this observer code any view controller else it is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126307/discussion-between-azat-and-dravidian).

Answer (score 1):

```
 func downloadUserData(){
   if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
    print("AZAT: download user data id \(currentUser.uid))")
     DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid).observe(  .value, with: {(snapshot) in 

    if let lastNameReceived = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["lastName"] as? String{
     print("lastName value is \(lastNameReceived)")
   }
     if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
        print("AZAT: userdict is \(userDict)")
         let user = User(userData: userDict)
           self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
         }
        })
    }
}
```